# how to get date difference between two dates using DateDiff Excluding the weekends

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to get difference between two dates using the datediff and i want to exclude the weekends.The Code below.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [uSerial] " +", DATEDIFF(dd,[RestartDate],getDate()) as statusDuration ,[cutRefs] " "FROM [dbo].[tblFTTH_Fault_Tool]", conn);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

kindly assist.

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are no clairvoyants here. Where are you struggle? Example data? What's not working?

Comment: Try running the same query directly on the db via SQL management studio and play around with it until you get expected output. We don't what is the expected output so very difficult to provide you a solution.

Comment: I developed a web application that adds data to sql server,including the start date and committed date, so i am calculating the duration between the start date and committed date using the DateDiff, i want to get the number of days between the start date and the committed date but excluding the weekends.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

and result is

DiffDate
61

Comment: hi i tried it and still counting the weekends.

Comment: it return date so you have convert date to weekend

Comment: you will try it
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @dFrom, @dTo)/7+1
    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,@dFrom) IN (1,7) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,@dTo) IN (1,7) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END